# Google Auto complete API

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I have a question related to google auto complete API, my auto complete for addresses question accounts for all the addresses around US but I want the auto complete to show only the addresses for the zipcode that the user has selected on the previous step. Anyone has any idea on how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Nancy

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a form with zipcode and address fields, set `disabled` to the address fields
2. Get the address with `Place(s) Autocomplete API` by the zipcode
3. Assign the address the the input fields

Which part do you want to ask?